# What's a good way to implement a "stop/cancel" button to stop a thread (that ins't a background worker)

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a WPF application that does a lot of talking to a remote server, so to keep the UI nice and responsive I put those operations in a second thread. There are a few possible, though unlikely, instances where that thread would just hang, blocking forever. Is there a simple way for me to implement a "cancel" button that doesn't involve calling thread.Abort()? I see a lot of people advise against using that, and I don't want to leave any unreleased resources. Perhaps a way to force the thread to throw an exception?

I specify in the title that this isn't a background worker because the program doesn't use those. It's already coded up with plain old threads.

Comment: If you don't want the thread to hang, fix those cases so it doesn't.

Comment: what are the cases that "just hang, blocking forever"? fix those!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Cases that the program alone can't decide if something has gone wrong, it requires some user decision. Also, in other instances where the program needs to stop the thread itself (such as a connection error, which it needs to reestablish the connection and restart the thread) I would like to use the same canceling method

Comment: "Perhaps a way to force the thread to throw an exception?" -- that's what Thread.Abort does.

Comment: Fundamentally, the answer is this: With the thread's cooperation, you can stop it any way you want to. Without the thread's cooperation, there is no safe way to do it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Ah I was hoping there was a way I could cleanly kill a thread without needing a lot of extra safety logic, but that doesn't appear to be the case

Comment: You cannot kill a thread cleanly without its cooperation, after all, it might be doing something that cannot be safely interrupted. How would you know when it's safe without the thread telling you somehow?

Comment: Are u opposed to backgroundworker because it would be a lot re-coding or is there something backgroundworker would not handle?

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely agree with comments that you need to fix what's broken, because that's the real issue, but if you can't at the moment, and need to continue operating. If you are on .Net 4.0, use the Task library. You can create a task and pass it an action that will execute on a different thread. The key is that you can pass a cancellation token to that task.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx

if you fire the same action over and over, you can also check the task status and do something about that.

```
//this is just a sample
 if (myTask != null) //meaning it's still exe'ing your action
{
    if (myTask.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted) //there's some kind of a problem with exe'ing it
    myTask = null; // could reset to run the action again
    else
        return; //let the task finish
}

myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew (() =>
        {
            ExecuteUMyAction ();
        });
```